# bootstrap 3 modal in meteor not showing

Tags: modal-dialog, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a bootstrap 3 modal to pop in a meteor app without any success at all.  Everything seems to be in place, I've scoured here and else where and it simply won't work.

The HTML is

```
<!-- A modal that contains the bigger view of the image selected -->
<template name="projectImageModal">
  <div class="modal fade in show" id="projectImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <p> Hi There</p>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <p> Hi There again</p>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Big Image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'bigProjectImage' file=image}}" alt="..." class="img-rounded">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Which is triggered from a click event on an image thumbnail (which is working according to console.log

The code trying to show the dialog is

```
Template.projectImageItem.events = {
    "click .open-modal" : function(e,t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Session.set("selectedImageId", t.data._id);
        console.log("Image ID: "+ Session.get("selectedImageId"));          
        //var stuff=$('#projectImageModal');
        //console.log(stuff);
        //stuff.modal('show');
//      $('#projectImageModal').modal().modal("show");
        $("#projectImageModal").modal("show");
        //$('#projectImageModal').modal('show');
        //$('.projectImageModal').modal('show');
    }
};
```

Which is largely pulled directly from the cfs-file-handler example (which doesn't used bootstrap and calls the modal().modal("show") version to get the modal to pop).

You can see the variations I've tried.  The console shows that the event is fired, the selector seems to be working but.. the modal NEVER pops.

Thanks.  Peter.

Comment: `class="modal fade in show"` means your modal is already shown? Or is this a typo? Except for this your code looks correct. Maybe make sure that `t.data` is not undefined or uncomment `Session.set("selectedImageId", t.data._id);`.

Comment: The class declaration doesn't show the dialog (I hove another that is working via a route that has the same declaration), t_data._id is defined as the shown by the console.log showing the correct ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the code below and it works as expected. If I add `show` to `class="modal fade in"` the modal immediately appears. If in your case it doesn't you are probably missing something else that is not shown in the sample code.

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>modal</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> projectImageItem}}
  {{> projectImageModal}}
</body>

<!-- A modal that contains the bigger view of the image selected -->
<template name="projectImageModal">
  <div class="modal fade in" id="projectImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Big Image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'bigProjectImage' file=image}}" alt="..." class="img-rounded">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="projectImageItem">
 <input type="button" class="open-modal" value="Show modal." />
</template>
```

JS

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.projectImageItem.events = {
        "click .open-modal" : function(e,t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#projectImageModal").modal("show");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Again Tobold I owe you a beer (this is getting expensive). I was missing creating the modal dialog (but not showing it) in the body. I was expecting it to be created when I tried to "show" it.